# Python prints statement for each line in txt file

Tags: python, list, int, arguments, multiplication

I want to take the user's input (an integer) and use it to multiply the 3rd argument in a list. I don't know how to go about this with the code i have currently:

```
def add_cart():
    cart_YorN = ""
    while cart_YorN not in ("y", "n"):
        cart_YorN = input("\nWould you like to add this item to your cart? ")
        if cart_YorN == "y":
            multiply = int(input("Okay, how many of this item would you like? \n")) #multiply is the variable that will carry the multiplication value
            receipt_list.#?????  #not sure what to do here
```

receipt.list is the list which contains 3 arguments and i want the third one to be multiplied by "multiply". 
Also, once this has been multiplied, will this update the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = receipt_list[2] * multiply
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
receipt_list[2] *= multiply
```

The third element of the list will be updated